# GNU/Linux: SAS-disk detected as /dev/sg7 - not as /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sas, gnu

I have just installed a SAS disk into a Debian server. It was detected correctly and everything was fine.

Then I moved the SAS disk to a different Debian server, the same hardware model and running same version of Debian, but here the SAS disk is detected as /dev/sg7 and not /dev/sdb.

`smartctl -a /dev/sg7` works fine, but `fdisk` and `cat` hang.

I tried putting the SAS disk in another slot: Same problem.

How can I force the SAS disk to be detected as /dev/sdb?

```
# uname -a
Linux maxwell 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg` says:

```
[171458.833581] scsi 0:1:5:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST91000640SS     0004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[171458.833795] scsi 0:1:5:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
```

Comment: Take a look at your loaded modules and udev rules.

Comment: Good idea. But alas no cigar. The working server has a subset of the modules in the failing server. udev only differs by mac-addresses.

Comment: `sg7` is the SCSI generic device, and everything you plug in gets one, whether it gets another device name or not. So that's kind of irrelevant. Check `dmesg` after you plug in the drive to see what's going on.

Comment: What SAS controller is in the new server? If it is a RAID controller, it might need some configuration (even if there was a single-disk array created on the old server with the same controller model, some kind of “import a foreign array” action may be needed to make the disk accessible on another controller).

Answer (score 1):

The two servers are the same model. They have the same modules loaded, but they are not *using* the same modules.

`lspci` shows that the two servers of the same model use very different RAID controllers (I *hate* it when vendors do that: F*cking change the model number if it is not the same model!).

On the server, where the disk works, you do not need to setup anything to access a disk that is not in a RAID. But on the server, where the disk does not work, you need to set the disk up as a volume in the RAID controller before Linux detects it.

So I have now done that, and the disk is now accessible.

Thanks to Falcon Momot and Sergey Vlasov for pointing me in the right direction.